# How to fix boxes coming in filename?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk, output

I am making a script which puts the man page for every Linux command into files.

man.sh:

```
while :
do
    echo -n "command:"
    read command
    man "$command" > op/"$command".txt
done
```

[commands.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zer-far/4541c003ac517c3756bfec9f16f22c6b/raw/e5e5b5a5438d43987a5642a4888fcb12300be548/commands.txt)

run.sh:

```
awk '{i=1; while(i<=NF){ print $((i++)); system("clear") }}' commands.txt | bash man.sh
```

When I run `bash run.sh` it is making files but the files are not named properly:

[image]

And they do not have anything in them:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: `"command"` is the name of a bash built-in, so is not a good variable name.

Comment: I think you should remove `system("clear")` which sends control characters to stdout.

Comment: Are you aware that manpages are already flat text files on your local disk? You could just use `cp` here.

Comment: @jordanm  Frequently they are gzip.

Comment: I ran whereis man and I got /usr/bin/man /usr/local/man /usr/share/man and I checked them but none of them have the man pages.

Comment: On my system `/usr/share/man/man2/lseek.2.gz` is the compressed file for `man lseek`

Comment: BTW you have infinite loop as `while :` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to do start with less infinite read:

```sh
while read -r command1;
do
    echo -n "command:"
    read command1
    man "$command1" > op/"$command".txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have over-engineered the whole thing a little:

```
while IFS= read -r cmd; do man "$cmd" > op/"$cmd".txt; done <"commands.txt"
```